# Reserve hardcoded memorymapped address in .NET before app starts up

Tags: c#, dll, unmanaged

We have a C# .NET application which binds to an unmanaged C dll.
The C dll uses CreateFileMapping() and MapViewOfFileEx() to share memory with other processes on the same machine.

MapViewOfFileEx() uses the last parameter (lpBaseAddress) and set it to 0x08000000 in our case. This is fine for all c/c++ applications if you call the initializing function in the dll early enough.
In c#, however, bigger application allocate a lot of memory before we even get the chance to call the dll's init function in the autogenerated static method Main(). (Small c# console apps work fine).

Is there a way to like preallocate the area 0x08000000 to 0x08400000 at startup of the .NET application before the automatic allocation for classes and stuff kicks in? Then it should be no problem to map the shared memory to 0x08000000 any time we like.

Restrictions:
The obvious solutions cannot be applied here.

- It is not possible to use a dynamically assigned virtual address by calling MapViewOfFile as this would require heavy changes in the C dll which currently works with absolute pointers in all processes.
- It is also not possible to negotiate a common base address between all processes, as they don't startup at the same time.

Comment: Re: _"a common base address between all processes"_; I thought that each process has its own address space…? So how can they have a *common* base address?

Comment: All processes share pointers to internal structures within the shared memory block. So a pointer to the second integer (let it be 42UL) would have its address on 0x08000004. Only if all processes have the same "virtual" base address, they get 42UL if they do
int my_var = *0x08000004

Comment: It is technically possible.  You'll have to write an unmanaged EXE in C++ that loads the CLR dynamically, after reserving the address space with VirtualAlloc().  You can then call VirtualFree() just before you let that code create the view.  Google "ICLRMetaHost".

Comment: ICLRMetaHost is an interresting approach, not totally lightweight, though. I have hoped to be able to get access to a pre-init hook or something similar within the .NET startup phase.

Comment: Our current "solution" for this issue is, that we moved back the shared memory address to 0x40000000.
This is late enough for our C# applications as memory is allocated from the beginning (at least in Win7). Let's wait until ASLR will kick in here, as well...